# How to implement immediate parent selector in SASS, SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have HTML layout as below:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Compiled CSS should look like:

```
.card{
}

.card .section .item{
}

.card .section .item+.item{
}
```

What I'm writing in SCSS:

```
.card{

    .section{

        .item{

            &+&{
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can we have something like `& + &`, which is not working, I do not want to write,

```
.card{

    .section{

        .item{
        }
        .item+.item{
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `&+.item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following **scss** did the trick:

```
.card{

    .section{

        .item{

            &+.item{
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could remove the '&' from your example and it would still work. This is basic nesting in Sass.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the parent selector, you can't use two `&` because then you'd be out of the scope.  In that case, just go up one block.

Ex:

```
#main {
  color: black;
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    &:hover { color: red; } /* Look at notes below */
  }
}
```

Compiles to

```
#main {
  color: black; }
  #main a {
    font-weight: bold; }
    #main a:hover { /* parent selector is replaced :D  */
      color: red; }
```

If you used two `&` adjacently you would be in the parent of the parent, which wouldn't make sense since you can just write your sass or scss one code block higher in the hierarchy.

[DOCUMENTATION: Referencing Parent Selectors: &](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

Comment: The ampersand doesn't step back one level at a time, rather it represents the entire selector up to that point, e.g.:
`.l1{ .l2{ .l3{ &.alt{color: chucknorris;}}}}` produces `.l1 .l2 .l3.alt {color: chucknorris;}` but using 2 ampersands, like `.l1{ .l2{ .l3{ & &.alt{color: chucknorris;}}}}` we get `.l1 .l2 .l3 .l1 .l2 .l3.alt {color: chucknorris;}`